# C++ iterator class causes R6025 run-time error in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have the following code, when I run the code below I get 'R6025 run-time error in Visual C++'

CommandParameterAndValue param( "Key", "value" );

parameters.AddParameter( &param );

parameters.HasParameter( "akeyval" );

I am lost, any ideas?  Is it something to do with the casting?

```
typedef std::vector<iCommandParameter *> ParamsVectorList;


class CommandParametersList
{
public:

   .... functions here ....

    void AddParameter( iCommandParameter *param );


    bool HasParameter( std::string parameterKey );

protected:
    ParamsVectorList m_parameters;
};



void CommandParametersList::AddParameter( iCommandParameter *param )
{
    m_parameters.push_back( param );
}


bool CommandParametersList::HasParameter( std::string parameterKey )
{
    ParamsVectorList::iterator it;
    CommandParameterAndValue *paramItem = NULL;
    bool returnValue = false;

    for ( it = m_parameters.begin(); it != m_parameters.end(); it++ )
    {
        paramItem = static_cast<CommandParameterAndValue *>( *it );

        if ( paramItem->GetKey().compare( parameterKey ) == 0 )
        {
            returnValue = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: What is *CommandParameterAndValue*?

Comment: The static cast should be a dynamic cast.  If the value is NULL, continue.  Are all the entries CommandParameterAndValue?  If they are not, that is what your problem is.  Is GetKey a virtual function?

Answer (score 0):

I need more information to give a complete answer, but if you look here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/125749

That run-time error means you tried to call a pure virtual function - it couldn't find an implementation.  I would suggest running through a debugger and finding which line of code throws this error.  Than it should be easy to understand and fix.  It's probably happening here:

```
if ( paramItem->GetKey().compare( parameterKey ) == 0 )
```

Comment: if ( paramItem->GetKey().compare( parameterKey ) == 0 ) is the culprit, parameterKey is perfectly valid, it's paramItem that is invalid and has blank key and value.